# Configuración correcta del shim usando deps y exports en require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Estoy tratando de entender **require.js** más a fondo: sé cómo crear, cómo llamar los módulos o cómo crearlos, entre otras cosas.

En una práctica que estaba realizando para entender cómo y cuándo usar el `shim`, realicé lo siguiente:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'js',
  paths : {
    jquery : ['libs/jquery-1.12.0.min','libs/jquery-2.2.0.min'],
    IndexTpl: 'app/Index_Tpl',
    IndexCtrl: 'app/Index_Ctrl',
    MenuTpl: 'app/Menu_Tpl',
    MenuCtrl: 'app/Menu_Ctrl'
  },
  shim: {
    IndexTpl: ['jquery'],
    MenuTpl: ['jquery']
  }
});
```

Como se puede observar el módulo del index y del menú, requieren de jquery para funcionar correctamente, entonces cargué de esta forma basándome en ejemplos que vi en internet, pero sin usar `deps` y `exports`, pero tengo un par de dudas que espero puedan ayudarme a resolver.

1. ¿Es necesario que tenga un orden los módulos que se van a cargar mediante esta forma, o simplemente no importa el orden?
2. ¿Puede existir algún error al no utilizar `deps` y `exports` en la estructura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lees la [documentación](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) de `requirejs` verás como la sección `shim` solo se usa para configurar las dependencias con librerías antiguas que no están preparadas para trabajar con módulo `AMD` que son los que gestiona `requirejs`

Actualmente casi todas las librerías están preparadas par ello e incluyen código para trabajar con los diferentes sistemas de módulos por lo que **no es necesario** usar esta configuración.

En tu caso la configuración sería:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'js',
  paths : {
    jquery : ['libs/jquery-1.12.0.min','libs/jquery-2.2.0.min'],
    IndexTpl: 'app/Index_Tpl',
    IndexCtrl: 'app/Index_Ctrl',
    MenuTpl: 'app/Menu_Tpl',
    MenuCtrl: 'app/Menu_Ctrl'
  }
});
```

Las dependencias con `jquery` se establecen en cada módulo:

**Archivo app/Index_Tpl**

```
define(['jquery', 'IndexCtrl'], function ($, IndexCtrl){ 

...

});
```

**>¿Configurar los `shim` puede aumentar la velocidad de carga?**

No, los `shim` solo se utilizan para adaptar librerías antiguas para que `requirejs` sea capaz de cargarlas de forma asíncrona y que se puedan configurar las dependencias.

Con lo que se puede ganar velocidad de carga es utilizando la utilidad [´r.js´](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) con la que se pueden concatenar y comprimir todos los archivos en uno por lo que solo se realizará una petición a servidor

Comment: Y entonces, no sirve de una manera por ejemplo que la carga sea desde el shim o eso no aumenta la velocidad de carga

Comment: Hola @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales, he actualizado mi respuesta para intentar aclarar tus dudas. Saludos

Comment: Gracias no había podido ingresar